# SpringBoot: Get method not producing expected XML elements

Tags: xml, spring-boot, jaxb, spring-restcontroller

I have a REST service implemented using spring boot that returns a List of objects. The response is of XML type

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/member/products/{memberNumber}", produces = {
      "application/xml", "text/xml"})
public List<MemberProduct> getMemberProducts
      (@PathVariable String memberNumber,
          @RequestHeader(USER_CONTEXT_HEADER_PARAM) String userContext) {
    validateUserContext(userContext);
    return repository.findByMemberNumber(memberNumber)
        .map(member -> {
          return member.getMemberProducts();
        })
        .orElseThrow(() ->
            new MemberNotFoundException(memberNumber));
  }
```

The response XML I expect is of the format

```
<MemberProducts>
  <MemberProduct>Value1</MemberProduct>
  <MemberProduct>Value2</MemberProduct>
</MemberProducts>
```

But what I get is response in the below format

```
<List>
   <Item>Value1</Item>
   <Item>Value2</Item>
</List>
```

`Member` class has other methods like `memberTaxDetails`, `memberAddresses`, `memberContactDetails`. I could see the `Member` Products as expected when `Member` object is retrieved.This occurs only for the Collection object.  Is there a way to control the correct format?

Comment: There is no `MembersProducts` element, only a regular list. The response is being generated by Jackson not Jaxb. If you want the collection you should introduce a `MemberProducts` definition and put the products in there, instead of a regular l ist.

Comment: Thanks, Deinum for responding. It worked after setting the collection to MemberProducts  and returning MemberProducts.